# Basic Jquery not working properly - sanity check please

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am using the following Jquery on label elements to add or remove a class depending on it's current state.

```
$('label').click(function(){
if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){
    //alert('its classy');
    $(this).removeClass('selected')
} else {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    //alert('its NOT classy');
    }
});
```

As far as I am concerned it should work! However in Firefox this requires a double-click and in Chrome it doesn't work at all.

Currently this is the only Javascript of any kind on the page so it's not being broken by any plugins or anything like that.

The relevant html of the element looks like this:-

```
<label class="">Filter item<input type="checkbox" /></label>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: p.s: [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) may be your friend.

Comment: It seems like Chrome doesn't like the `input` being a child of the `label`. Move the `input` outside and it works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Your `click` event will get triggered twice if you nest the `input` tag. Appended details to answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this is the case, but you can fix the problem by moving the `input` outside of the `label`:

```
<label for="yourCheckbox">Filter item</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="yourCheckbox" />
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/CBPat/2/). Note that the example uses `toggleClass` as suggested by @Matt in the comment on your question. I've tried it in both Chrome and Firefox and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Matt It looks like you both hit the nail on the head there toggleClass is a much cleaner way of doing what I was attempting to do. Many thanks for your help

Comment: I would be interested to know why it doesn't work when the `input` is inside the `label`... I'm trying to work it out but no luck so far!

Comment: This will not work as expected when the checkbox is clicked instead of the label.

Comment: @ShawnChin - True, you would need to bind to the `change` event instead of the `click` event. Edit: Just noticed that's what you've done in your answer!

Comment: I have now asked a question to try and get an answer as to why this is the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386448/strange-behaviour-of-toggleclass-with-label-element

Comment: @JamesAllardice I've just addressed this in my answer here, but since you've posted another Q, I've paraphrased the answer there as well.

Comment: @ShawnChin - Oh yeah, you hadn't edited your answer when I wrote the question. Oh well, you can just get the extra rep from writing it out again :)

Comment: I have no objections to extra rep ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guess the reason why you're placing the `input` inside the `label` is so you can toggle the "selected" class depending on the status of the checkbox, and have it work when the click is applied to either the label or the checkbox.

Here's one way to achieve that while keeping `label` and `input` separate: http://jsfiddle.net/pkuCe/

```
$('#cb').change(function(){
    $("label[for=cb]").toggleClass("selected", this.checked);
});
```

This sets the class on `label` depending on the status of the checkbox, and should work when either the checkbox or the label is clicked.

---

#### Why is your current approach not working?

From [the specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1), there's nothing wrong with nesting `input` within the `label` tag:

> `for = idref [CS]`
>
> > This attribute explicitly associates the label being defined with another control. When present, the value of this attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of some other control in the same document. **When absent, the label being defined is associated with the element's contents.**

However, it looks like the problem you have stems from the fact that the `click` event is being triggered twice (thus nullifying the toggle) when you have a nested `input` element. I haven't tested it on all browsers, but seems to happen in FF8.

Try clicking on the label in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/cRnJS/

Apparently, clicks on `label` elements triggers a `click` event on its associated `input` (which is why the check/uncheck works) and this event bubbles upwards hence triggering it a second time in the parent `label`.

Conclusions?

1. HTML specs wise you can have `input` nested within a `label`, but it might be wise to leave them separate
2. Use the `change` event instead of `click`. (note: you can have multiple labels for each `input`)

Comment: This is why I like Stack Overflow so much. This helps to really understand the issue which is just as important as finding a working solution to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
<label class="" for="FilterItem">Filter item</label>
<input id="FilterItem" type="checkbox" />
```