# Strange behaviour of toggleClass with label element

Tags: jquery

Earlier today I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385765/basic-jquery-not-working-properly-sanity-check-please/). The question is about toggling a class on a `label` element with jQuery. Consider the following HTML:

```
<label id="test">Test <input type="checkbox"></label>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("testClass");
});
```

When I click on the `label` I would expect the `testClass` class to be applied to that element (as it doesn't have that class when the page loads). However, nothing happens. See it for yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/CBPat/5/). I haven't tried it in IE, but it doesn't work correctly in Chrome or Firefox. I believe it will work in IE from the question linked to previously.

Stepping through the [`toggleClass` method in the jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7rc2/src/attributes.js#L109), what seems to happen is the class gets added and removed again straight away.

If you move the `input` element outside  of the `label`, the class is added as expected:

```
<label id="test" for="cb">Test</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">
```

You can see that one in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/CBPat/4/). So, my question is why does the first example not appear to add the class on the first click? Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem stems from the fact that the `click` event is being triggered twice (thus nullifying the toggle) when you have a nested `input` element. I haven't tested it on all browsers, but this seems to happen in FF8.

Try clicking on the label in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/cRnJS/

Apparently, clicks on `label` elements triggers a `click` event on its associated `input` (which is why the check/uncheck works) and this event bubbles upwards hence triggering it a second time in the parent `label`.

Comment: Ahh can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks :)