# jQuery toggleClass doesn't work with label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why doesn't `toggleClass()` work with label element? And how can I fix it?

If you only click on the label (not the checkbox) you'll see the color doesn't change.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsgdquwd/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.filter-set label').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-set">
  <ul>
    <li><label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> label 1</label></li>
    <li><label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> label 2</label></li>
    <li><label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> label 3</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need `change` event binding instead of `click`

```
$('.filter-set label').change(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/8gz0jsnq/5/

**Explanation :**

It turns out that when you `click` on the label, it also invokes the `click` event on the `input:checkbox` ( because of nested element wrapping ). Because of this, the 1st event on the label does sets the class `'active'` correctly , however with the subsequent click event on the `checkbox` toggles it back to `empty` ( basically removes the class '`active`').

The effects of the above mentioned can be seen here : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/8gz0jsnq/6/

Binding a `change` event would only trigger the event once ( only for `checkbox` ) which would toggle the class correctly.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working fine, I didn't know you can use change() on a label.

Comment: The change event on label is invalid. It would trigger it for checkbox, hence executing only once.

Comment: I have a related question it would be great if you can answer as well, see http://jsfiddle.net/8gz0jsnq/7/ is it possible to remove the hover state on the 2nd click? when checkbox changed from checked to unchecked.

Comment: You might need to change some logic to do that. Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/8gz0jsnq/9/

Comment: Sure. Glad to help : ). Happy Friday !!

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do here is use the checkbox change event instead:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});
```

Works when clicking on the checkbox directly and on the label:

https://jsfiddle.net/s6fx1Lez/

For more details on why this is happening:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8386513/660694

Comment: What you have mentioned is delegation, not binding. ( Might wanna correct that in the answer )